# Inkscape equivalent of Blob Tool

Tags: inkscape

Is there any tool/plugin to have functionality of Adobe Illustrator's `Blob Tool`?

Essentially, I have some artwork which has been already filled with `Fill Bounded Area` tool. Now I want to perform some detailing by adding some different colors in different parts of my illustration.

Roundabout way of doing it to just copy paste shape on which I want detailed work and then use `Eraser` to remove unwanted things. Or use brush to draw things and then combine them with Union operations. But that is very tedious way to achieve simple thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent to the blob brush, and as far as I know there's no plugin to do it.

However there may be ways you could speed up what your are doing.

E.g., you can use the Calligraphic Brush tool, then directly after using the tool you can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, which is the shortcut for a Unite operation.

If you draw another Calligraphic Brush shape on top of another the same colour, you can do *Edit > Select Same > Fill colour* *, then again hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to Unite them.

*** *Note*** there's no default keyboard shortcut for "Edit > Select same > Fill Colour", but you could add one in the Preferences to speed this up even more.

You can also draw objects you want to unite on separate layers, and if you have the *Preferences > Behaviour > Selecting > Select only within current layer* option checked, then you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to unite them all in one go.